# questiopn about linearly dependent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a 7 vectors with 7 dimensions in $\mathbb{Z_2}$. Which way would be the fastest to find out weather they are linearly dependent or not.

The vectors are $v_i$ with $0\le i,x \le 6$ with the components $x_i$.
For vector $v_i$ the components $x_{i-1},x_{i},x_{i+1} = 1$. The rest are zeros.

Comment: This gives a band matrix whose determinant can be computed easily. When it is zero, the vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: Nut how am I able to compute them easily. All algorithms i have seen so far are really time consuming.

Comment: There is a formula in general for the determinant of these matrices you can use. So no time consuming algorithm. Just searching, or googling (I know, also time consuming).

Comment: Ok I found the recursive method, with that amount of zeros i have in this case that should be fine. Is there another way? We didn't cover matrix's in class, only next week so there should be a way to solve this without using that.

Comment: If it has any repeated rows or columns its automatically dependent. Also, you can row reduce the matrix to see if It is equivalent to the identity matrix. Your matrix is over a finite field though, I'd have to think about how your calc would deal with that but my guess is the result would be the same. Also your calc will compute determinant instantly.